# Can I get coordinate of canvas when Horizontal dragging in GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 Rectangles canvas in the same GestureDetector and then when I touch on some rectangle, I want to drag the rectangle but the rest of rectangles are not movable.
and I want to get a current Offset Of the dragged canvas for dragging them. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NotificationListener`. Just wrap your screen into NotificationListener and check events. Here is JUST an example for ListView. Also drag events should be available.
Secondly, you can check `GestureDetector` widget(just wrap your screen and provide necessary callbacks)

In addition please check https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                if (scrollNotification is ScrollStartNotification) {
                  _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                  _onUpdateScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                } else if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
                  _onEndScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
                }
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 30,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text("Index : $index"));
                },
              ),
            ),
```